# Как шагать по массиву во время отладки?

Tags: c#

Как шагать по массиву во время отладки ?

Массив например из 2кк значений

Как посмотреть значения во время отладки в районе 1кк например ?

Обычно бегал с помощью `PageDown` - но тут сильно долго держать xD

IDE visual strudio 2019

Comment: @RomanKonoval visual strudio 2019

Comment: @aepot отлучался

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтоб посмотреть значение выражение можно воспользоваться окном QuickWatch: `Debug -> QuickWatch` или `Shift + F9`. Там вводите выражение типа: `myarray[1000]` и смотрите значение.

Если же нужно пропустить какое-то количество срабатываний точки останова, то в настройках точки останова можно задать, чтобы пропустить какое-то количество  срабатываний (hit count) или задать условное выражение, когда она должна срабатывать (можно, например, на индекс цикла):

[image: точка останова настройки]

Comment: Во время останова - при наведению на переменную массива можно смотреть значения массива - вот в этот момент можно как то быстро опуститься к нужному значению ?

Comment: @Алексей нет, используйте окно Watch.